# Is it possible to delete specific pages from the CEF cache?

Tags: winforms, cefsharp

Consider this scenario:

1. in Search mode, the program performs a search for a given word in local html files and displays a list of links to the found files.
2. on click on a link, the file is read to memory, the found words are marked using HAP and the modified html is fed to the CefSharp browser.
3. after exiting Search mode, in Browsing mode, the browser will pull the same file from the cache and display it, markings and all, which may or may not be desirable.

So the question is: can those marked files be deleted from the cache when exiting Search mode?

Thank you.

Comment: The easiest option would be to simply use a different `ChromiumWebBrowser` instance with a new `RequestContext`, if you don't provide a `CachePath` then an in memory cache will be used. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#request-context-browser-isolation

Comment: @amaitland Thank you for your answer, but I meant deleting **specific** pages from the cache. Sorry for the vague wording, I updated the question.

Comment: You might be able to use https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/CacheStorage/ to achieve this. I've never tried, you'd have to test to see if it's feasible. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3165 for generic details on sending DevTools commands directly to the browser.

Comment: @amaitland Thank you. I will look into it and report here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn’t make work the CromeDevTools way that was suggested here (although I confess I didn’t spend much time on it) so here is my ugly solution:
Maintain a List of all the marked files during Search mode. In browsing mode, check if the target file is in the list and if it is (meaning that it was marked) just read it afresh from disc to a HtmlDocument in memory and feed it to the browser, thus bypassing the cache.